# new row doesnot add to the datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, datagridview

I am a beginner in c#. I have a [XML file (xmlfile.xml)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/87374848/xmlfile.xml) which has some text in it.

On Form Load Event I am reading the XML file and showing it in `datagridview1` of `mainForm` Form.

I am using below code to do this

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"D:\xmlfile.xml");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dataGridView1.Tag = ds;   /* TAG */
```

I have another form `noteForm` in which I have `textBox1` and `btnSub` button. Whenever the user clicks on `btnSub` button `textBox1.Text` should be added to the `dataGridView1` of the `mainForm`

I am trying the below code to do this

```
            string strTitle;
            string[] row = new string[] { strTitle, DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/y"), "checked" };
            _parent.dataGridView1.Tag.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
            _parent.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            _parent.dataGridView1.DataSource = _parent.dataGridView1.Tag.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

The above code is showing error -- "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."

I cant understand what is this error. Please help.

**_parent is just `mainForm` form in `noteForm`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add new row to your DataSet `ds` not to  `dataGridView1`

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row)
```

**EDIT**

```
string strTitle;
string[] row = new string[] { strTitle, DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/y"), "checked" };
DataSet ds = (DataSet)_parent.dataGridView1.Tag;
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: The `dataset` is in `mainForm`. How to add it in `subForm`. I dont know please help.

Comment: You can set `ds` to `dataGridView1.Tag` property to access it later, or declare it as a public field in `_parent`

Comment: I have given `dataGridView1.Tag = ds;` in `mainForm` and `DataSet ds = _parent.dataGridView1.Tag;` in `noteForm` but in `noteForm` I dont know how to do that.(I am going through many links here)

Comment: I don't understand your question, if you have the dataset in `noteform` add the row to it. `(DataSet ds = (DataSet)_parent.dataGridView1.Tag)`

Comment: I dont have dataset in `noteForm` but I added now. It is showing error "Cannot find table 0." . I have gone through one link it is saying to use datareader. Please suggest me what should I do.

Comment: @Mr_Green you should not add a DataSet to `noteForm`. you should find a way to access  the original `ds in mainForm` from `noteForm` (as using `Tag`)

Comment: I changed my code in the question. I am doing some small mistake. visual studio is showing scribbling to the `Tables[0]` in `noteForm` code.

Comment: See the edit. And i am going to scream if you ask one more question.

Comment: Thank you very much its working. but it is adding one empty row at starting. once again thankyou very much. :)